# Bochner integrability of mappings of Bochner integrable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose I have a Bochner integrable function, $t\mapsto u(t)\in X$, with $X$ a separable Banach space, and $0\leq t\leq T<\infty$.  If I introduce a mapping $f:[0,T]\times X\to X$, under what assumptions will $t\mapsto f(t,u(t))$ be Bochner integrable?  Is joint measurabiity of $f$ sufficient?  Continuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is separable, then joint measurability (inverse images of all balls are measurable) is sufficient. This is a property of [Bochner measurability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_measurable_function)